# Automatically close open files in a specific directory

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is it possible using VBA to close all open files in a given directory, with out knowing filename/extension etc...

EDIT .....

I have directories linked to records, for example the record for Joe Bloggs has a directory created related to the name eg Bloggs, Joe

If the user changes the records names, the folder name therefore has to reflect this.

Currently I can change the directory name no problem if all associated files are closed. Also if these files are open I can prompt the user to close the associated files.

I was wondering would it be possible to close/ prompt to save the files?

EDIT AGAIN .....

To further complicate matters there are further directories in the directory tree that relate to each record. (I should have been clearer at the beginning, the database stores info on household insurance claims)

So you have a directory structure like so:

User Name _ID  \ 1st line of Property Address _ID \ Claim No _ID

Thanks in advance for any help

Cheers

Noel

Comment: Why would you want to risk corrupting a file by force closing it? I think what your asking to do is completely inadvisable. If there are open files in the path, you just tell the user, and either they close the files or you can't complete the rename.

Comment: @David, taken on board your advice and will avoid forcing the closure of open files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can uncomplify this thing.  Your Users table should have a primary key, user_id.  Say Joe Bloggs' user_id is 27.  Create the folder for him as C:\userdirs\27.  If Joe's name is later changed, his user_id and user folder can stay the same.

If your users need access to those folders by user name rather than user_id, create shortcuts for them.

```
Public Function CreateUserDirShortcut(ByVal pLinkFolder As String, _
        ByVal pLinkName As String, _
        ByVal pTargetFolder As String) As Boolean

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objLink As Object
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim blnReturn As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(pLinkFolder & Chr(92) & pLinkName & ".lnk")
    objLink.Description = pLinkName
    objLink.TargetPath = pTargetFolder
    objLink.Save
    blnReturn = True

ExitHere:
    Set objLink = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
    CreateUserDirShortcut = blnReturn
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure CreateUserDirShortcut"
    MsgBox strMsg
    blnReturn = False
    GoTo ExitHere
End Function
```

Then you can create a shortcut to Joe Bloggs' user directory like this:

```
CreateUserDirShortcut "C:\shortcuts", "Bloggs, Joe", "C:\userdirs\27")
```

Comment: @HansUp Cheers for the idea. I was currently using ID in the directory name but had never entertained this idea. Could certainly save me a bit of trouble. My only concern is when the user would be confronted with the ID numbers only, as would happen when they move up and down directories and wouldn't see the user friendly shortcuts.

Comment: @glinch Not sure I understand.  If instead you create the shortcuts in the same folder as the user directories (C:\userdirs), anyone browsing there in Windows Explorer could see both the numbered folders and the name-based shortcuts.  Could that work?

Comment: @HansUP Sorry, I should have been clearer with my problem. I have added an edit above. The only problem with your suggestion would be that the directory would become fairly large, with a large number of numbered folders that may be a bit confusing. Wouldn't be the end of the world though, just wouldn't appear very tidy.

Comment: If the total item count for the numbered folders plus shortcuts is too large, consider dividing them into 26 subfolders based on the first letter of the last name.  Although more complicated, still seems to me it would be easier than trying to determine whether files are open in a folder so you can rename it.

Comment: @HansUp Cheers for the idea here, I may go with David's advice for the moment although I can definitely appreciate how this could be a useful technique. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: @glinch I definitely agree with David's recommendation not to force close open files.  However, if the user opens a file from the name-based shortcut, the file opens in association with the underlying numbered folder.  Therefore you can remove or modify the shortcut without concern about open files.

Comment: @HansUp Just returning to this thread to say that your above solution was used in the end by myself. As you mentioned above, using shortcuts resolved many issues. To make the folders tidier (so to speak) the actual folders that the shortcuts point to are set as hidden folders and the users computers cannot view these files/folders. Seems to work fine. thanks for the advice @hansup and I hope that this info may help somebody else.